# Combining single- and multi- select drop-down in one form. How to dismiss the drop-down?

Tags: interaction-design, dropdown, multi-selection, drop-down-list

[image]

How to dismiss the drop-down in single-select and multi-select cases?

For **single-select**, the obvious option is to dismiss the drop-down on selection.

For **multi-select**, drop-down should stay open on selection, and can be dismissed with a button, or clicking outside.

**Question:** Will it be confusing for people to have two models of interaction side-by-side? What is the best strategy here?

Mind that cost of error ((wrong selection) is small. Nothing is saved, or processed, or launched into the space when option is selected.

*Examples from the web are welcome in the comments section.*